# What is the graphic design term for this sort of color splashes?

Tags: terminology, style-identification

[image]
What is the graphic design term using for this (mean this color splashes)?

And in a nutshell, is there a way to draw scenes like this in PS or AI?

Comment: “We don't make mistakes, just happy little accidents.” -- Bob Ross

Comment: Surely [S. Brakhage's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stan_Brakhage) work qualifies... this makes me think of a "typical" frame of one of his movies.

Answer (score 3):

## Marbling

The base is **marbling**, from there the different options like [paint marbling](https://www.google.com/search?q=paint%20marbling&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZq6WM5pPgAhVCURoKHW1WARMQ_AUIDigB&biw=1533&bih=1200), [color marbling](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1533&bih=1200&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=7bJQXOzZKLKNlwTI-bWwDg&q=color%20marbling&oq=color%20marbling&gs_l=img.3..0i19.73294.76398..76737...1.0..0.408.3544.1j6j1j6j1......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0j35i39j0i67j0i10j0i30j0i5i30.2ee08rnImps), [liquid marbling](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1533&bih=1200&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=O7NQXOSDCpGKrwTyirv4CA&q=liquid%20marbling&oq=liquid%20marbling&gs_l=img.3..35i39l2j0i7i30i19.16590.17364..17691...0.0..0.113.653.0j6......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i8i7i30.6p8G6r7XpMk) and the different reproduction techniques, some of them appear as [marble art](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1533&bih=1200&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=27JQXK3PMu2UlwSO7qTwCQ&q=marble%20art&oq=marble%20art&gs_l=img.3..0l2j0i30l8.15126.16677..17093...0.0..0.81.746.10......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39j0i67.4cueJvkD8oA).

The [paper marbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_marbling) is a very old technique whose origin is similar to the photo of the question and the creation process is similar to the one reproduced in this tutorial from forthemakers.com

[**Acrylic paint marbling**](https://www.forthemakers.com/tutorials/acrylic-paint-marbling)

[image]

There are several tutorials on the internet using the **Twirl Brush** in Illustrator or the **Liquify Effect** in Photoshop. Just search for [Illustrator marbling](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1533&bih=1200&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=ULZQXOS_G4qoa9nXk9AO&q=illustrator%20marbling&oq=illustrator%20marbling&gs_l=img.3..35i39.67856.69834..70217...0.0..0.95.829.11......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i8i7i30.ckNhftNtNjA) or [Photoshop Marbling](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1533&bih=1200&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=vLVQXOLxAsKwafPxuIAG&q=photoshop%20marbling&oq=photoshop%20marbling&gs_l=img.3..0i8i30.145042.146839..147448...0.0..0.89.707.9......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i7i30j0i8i7i30.K5DPfV-HEk0#imgrc=_6mUVmVy3mzR4M:).

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a uniformly used term, but the closest term I can find is ["fluid art"](https://www.google.com/search?q=fluid+art&num=20&safe=off&es_sm=122&biw=1920&bih=955&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=O7-EVL9hiJg2rouB-Ak&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&dpr=1), or seemingly interchangeable term ["liquid art"](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&es_sm=122&biw=1920&bih=955&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=liquid+art&oq=liquid+art&gs_l=img.3..0l10.616.1492.0.1863.10.6.2.0.0.2.149.560.4j2.6.0.msedr...0...1c.1.58.img..9.1.77.pqTyibbF2Zg).

The same term seems to be used across [photos](https://www.behance.net/gallery/a-due-Colori/3367841), paintings, [3D renderings](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&es_sm=122&biw=1920&bih=955&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=liquid+art+rendering+3d&oq=liquid+art+rendering+3d&gs_l=img.3...21590.22041.0.22226.4.4.0.0.0.0.87.223.3.3.0.msedr...0...1c.1.58.img..4.0.0.386jbd8WWCI), and [videos](http://vimeo.com/82090537).

Comment: How appropriate: [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3rvUNcueFg) came out today :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find all sorts of Photoshop Paint Brushes of varying qualities that can produce this. Look for some high resolution paint textures and paint brushes. They'll be .abr format if they're actual brushes.

This might help get you started:

[Tutorial 9 - 250 Hi Res Splatter, Spray, & Watercolor Photoshop Brushes](http://www.tutorial9.net/downloads/250-free-hi-res-splatter-paint-watercolor-photoshop-brushes/)

Then its just playing with them. Layer them and adjust the colors, curves, opacity and such.